# Best way to page through results in SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a database table that contains RTF documents. I need to extract these programmatically (I am aware I can use a cursor to step through the table - I need to do some data manipulation).  I created a C# program that will do that, but the problem is that it can not load the whole table (about 2 million rows) into memory.

There is [a MSDN page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

That says there is basically two ways to loop through the data.

1. use the `DataAdapter.Fill` method to load page by page
2. run the query many times, iterating by using the primary key. Basically you run it once with a TOP 500 limit (or whatever) and PK > (last PK)

I have tried option 2, and it seems to work. But can I be sure I am pulling back all the data?  When I do a `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Document` it pulls back the same number of rows. Still, I'm nervous. Any tips for data validation?

Also which is faster?  The data query is pretty slow - I optimized the query as much as possible, but there is a ton of data to transport over the WAN.

Comment: What have you measured to take most time? The manipulation or the transfer? You should try to load stuff in one thread so you always have fresh data to manipulate and pulling it back in another.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19058/A-Neat-Solution-to-GridView-Custom-Paging

Comment: One other thought - what sort of manipulation is required? Could this and/or the validation be done on the server prior to pulling the data across the WAN? This way there'd be less data both (a) in transit & (b) in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer requires a lot more understanding of your true requirements. It's hard for me to imagine a recurring process or requirement where you have to regularly extract 2 million binary files to do some processing on them! If this is a one-time thing then alright, let's get 'er done!

Here are some initial thoughts:

1. Could you deploy your C# routine to SQL directly and execute everything via CLR?
2. Could you have run your C# app locally on the box and take advantage of [shared memory protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187662.aspx)?
3. Do you *have to* process every single row?  If, for instance, you're validating the structure of the RTF data has changes versus another file can you create hashes of each that can be compared?
4. If you *must* get all the data out, maybe try [exporting it](http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/10/exporting-binary-files-to-file-system.html) to local disk and the XCOPY'ing it to another location.
5. If want to get a chunk of rows at a time, create a table that just keeps a list of all ID's that have been processed.  When grabbing of the next 500 rows just find rows that aren't in that table yet. Of course, update that table with the new ID's that you've exported.
6. If you *must* do all this it could have a serious effect on OLTP performance.  Either throttle it to only run off hours or take a *.bak and process it on a separate box.  Actually, if this is a one-time thing, restore it to the same box that's running the SQL and use the shared memory protocol.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented a bunch of these suggestions.  This is a one time thing thank god.  I ended up just using the TOP N of the SELECT and WHERE PK > lastRecordPK as described in the MSDN document.  When I ran the query from SSMS it took 18 hours, using this methodology with the same query it only takes 4 hours.  I am running off production time so there is not much user impact.  I am running the program not on the server box for testing, but for the real thing I will certainly do that.